# Specify browser location for wct-local test

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component-tester

The Polymer Starter Kit contains web-component-tester for unit testing your custom elements.

In `wct.conf.json` you can specify the browsers to run the tests in.

```
{
  "suites": ["app/test"],
  "plugins": {
    "local": {
    "browsers": ["firefox"]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I launch the tests through gulp, wct is not able to find my local Firefox. I read at [GitHub](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester/issues/50) that wct uses launchpad to detect local browsers. Afaik, on a Windows machine, launchpad searches for Firefox in the default directory `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox"`. But I installed Firefox in a different directory.

Is there any way to configure the path to my Firefox dir in `wct.conf.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how it works in the config but you can set an environment variable:

```
LAUNCHPAD_CHROME=/c/Users/you/chromium-v85/chrome.exe npm test
```

Docs: https://github.com/bitovi/launchpad#environment-variables-impacting-local-browsers-detection